# Lock process in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need a way to prevent multiple run on a process on symfony 1.4.

Something like: when a user is running this process, the other user who tries to run this process will get a warning message inform that the process is running.

Is there a way to implement it without using database?

Comment: You can write a `.lock` file for example and check if this file exist when running the process. Do not forget to remove the `.lock` file when current user stop its process.

Comment: i've considered that solution. but if the user lost connection or a problem occur with server, the file won't be removed

Comment: But without using database, it will be hard. With, you can know if the user is idle (using sfPdoSessionStorage for example) since too long time and then reset the `.lock` file.

Comment: uhmmm, is there any kind of application's session that can be access by any user?

Comment: I want to know can we implement a global session that can be access by any user. So that when a user is running the process, i'll set value for session, and when the process finish or error occur with the server, the session will be removed. And other user can read this session to determine this process is running or not

Comment: Session are per user, it can't be shared. What you want to do is basically what I describe above. There is also: http://us2.php.net/flock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kirugan's method will probably work in most cases, but it's susceptible to race conditions and can get stuck in the event of a crash.

Here's a more robust solution. It uses PHP's file locking so you **know** the lock is atomic, and if you forget to release the lock later or your process crashes, it gets released automatically. By default, getting a lock is non-blocking (i.e. if the lock is already held by another process, `getLock()` will instantly return FALSE). However, you can have the call block (i.e. wait until the lock becomes available) if you'd like. Finally, you can have different locks for different parts of your code. Just use a different name for the lock.

The only requirement is that the directory returned by `getLockDir()` must be server-writable. Feel free to change the location of the lock dir.

Note: I think [flock](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)() may behave differently on Windows (I use linux), so double check that if its an issue for you.

**myLock.class.php**

```
class myLock
{
  /**
   * Creates a lockfile and acquires an exclusive lock on it.
   *
   * @param string $filename The name of the lockfile.
   * @param boolean $blocking Block until lock becomes available (default: don't block, just fail)
   * @return mixed Returns the lockfile, or FALSE if a lock could not be acquired.
   */
  public static function getLock($name, $blocking = false)
  {
    $filename = static::getLockDir() . '/' . $name;
    if (!preg_match('/\.lo?ck$/', $filename))
    {
      $filename .= '.lck';
    }
    if (!file_exists($filename))
    {
      file_put_contents($filename, '');
      chmod($filename, 0777); // if the file cant be opened for writing later, getting the lock will fail
    }
    $lockFile = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    if (!flock($lockFile, $blocking ? LOCK_EX : LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB))
    {
      fclose($lockFile);
      return false;
    }
    return $lockFile;
  }

  /**
   * Free a lock.
   *
   * @param resource $lockFile
   */
  public static function freeLock($lockFile)
  {
    if ($lockFile)
    {
      flock($lockFile, LOCK_UN);
      fclose($lockFile);
    }
  }

  public static function getLockDir()
  {
    return sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir') . '/data/lock';
  }
}
```

**How to use**

```
$lockFile = myLock::getLock('lock-name');
if ($lockFile) {

  // you have a lock here, do whatever you want

  myLock::freeLock($lockFile);
}
else {
  // you could not get the lock. show a message or throw an exception or whatever
}
```

Comment: Can you give example when `touch` can create race condition ?

Comment: Imagine this: you have two requests come in at the same time and both call lock(). Request A executes the if statement. $file does not exist, so it does not die. But it has not executed the `touch` line yet. Now request B executes the if statement. $file does not exist yet, so it doesn't die either. Now both requests think they have the lock. In my code, flock() is guaranteed to be atomic (it happens all at once and cannot be interrupted by the OS), so even if two processes execute that line one right after the other, only one will get the lock and the other will get FALSE.

Comment: So the problem isn't `touch`, its non-atomicity. Google "atomic operation" or check this for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability

Comment: @lyoshenka after using your code, i found that if server goes down - locking file still exists, which block other executions of the script. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: The existence of the lockfile shouldn't matter at all as long as the user opening the file has the right permissions. Can you tell me more about what's not working? Are you getting an error and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my functions for this:

```
function lock(){
   $file = __DIR__ . '/file.lock';
   if(file_exists($file)){
        /* exit or whatever you want */
        die('ALREADY LOCKED');
   }
   touch($file);
}
function unlock(){
    $file = __DIR__ . '/parser.lock';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        unlink($file);
    }else{
        echoln("unlock function: LOCK FILE NOT FOUND");
    }
}

function exitHandler(){
     echoln('exitHandler function: called');    
         unlock();
}
```

Use `lock` function in the beginning, and set `exitHandler` function in `register_shutdown_function()`. You can save this snippets as class with the same methods or save it like helper file